# How to add drawerIcon inside options in React Native

Tags: react-native

Here is my code:

```
<Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={StackNavigator}
        options={({route}) => {
          const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Billing';
          if (sideMenuDisabledScreens.includes(routeName))
            return {swipeEnabled: false};
        }}
      />
```

I am implementing drawer navigator in my application and I want to add icon for drawer item home. Inside options I have added route to disable drawer for particular screens. After adding the route disable code I am not able to mention icons for drawerIcon. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i get your point, you can have both properties just like this

```
options={({route}) => {
          const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) ?? 'Billing';
          if (sideMenuDisabledScreens.includes(routeName))
            return {swipeEnabled: false};
        },
       {
        drawerIcon: // add your comp here,
        title:" THIS is possible",
       }
    }
```

Hope ite helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: If i add this drawerIcon code disabling drawer for specific screens code is not working

Answer (score 0):

Add `drawerIcon` property like the following:

```js
drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
  <Image
    source={require('./chats-icon.png')}
    style={[{ tintColor: tintColor }]}
  />
),
```